# Prove equality of products and intersections of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here is the problem I am working on: Suppose $H$, $K$, and $N$ are subgroups of group $G$ with $H\le N$. Prove that $(HK)\cap N=H(K
\cap N)$. (The notation $HK$ refers to the subgroup made up of elements of the form hk where $h\in H$ and $k\in K$.)

My work so far: Let $x\in (HK) \cap N$, which means that $x$ is in both $HK$ and $N$. In other words, $x=n \in N$ and $x=hk$ for $h \in H$ and $k \in K$, so $hk=n$.

Now let $x\in H(K\cap N)$, which means that the products of any $h\in H$ and any $m$ in both $K$ and $N$ is in this subgroup, in other words $m=k\in K$ and $m=n\in N$. Each $x\in H(K\cap N)$ satisfies $x=hm$.

I don't know how I can get from $(HK)\cap N$ to $H(K\cap N)$ or vice versa; in fact, I am having trouble believing intuitively that the statement I'm supposed to be proving is even true. Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to prove is known as *Dedekind’s Modular Law* after the famous mathematician Richard Dedekind. It is a very useful tool in group theory and it’s proof can be found in many textbooks, for example M.I. Isaacs, Finite Group Theory.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! For anyone who may stumble across this question in the future, it is proving the modular law for groups.